# Is there a way to check what part of my code leaves file handles open

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

Is there a way to track the python process to check where a file is being opened. I have too many files open when I use `lsof` on my running process but I'm not sure where they are being opened.

```
ls /proc/$pid/fd/ | wc -l
```

I suspect one of the libraries I'm using might have not handled the files properly. Is there a way to isolate exactly which line in my python code the files are being opened?

In my code I work with 3rd party libraries to process thousands of media files and since they are being left open I receive the error

```
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

after running for a few minutes. Now I know raising the limit of open files is an option but this will just push the error to a later point of time.

Comment: are you opening the files using `open()` or using a `with open()` statement?

Comment: I'm using the `with` command, but like I said some file access are through other libraries. They are media files like audio ones.

Comment: Well, since you haven't provided your code snippet, I am shooting in the dark here. Is it possible that to *these libraries* you could send the file descriptor rather than the filename, so that you end up opening the file just once !

Comment: What do you mean by "too many" files open?  Presumably there is a reason that the libraries are opening files.

Comment: Updated the question with more details of what I mean by too many files

Comment: @RohitashwaNigam Thanks for the suggestion, I'm looking at it but I see at least 1 of my library that supports filenames only!

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to trace the `open` calls is to use an audit hook in Python. Note that this method would only trace Python `open` calls and not the system calls.

Let `fdmod.py` be a module file with a single function `foo`:

```
def foo():
    return open("/dev/zero", mode="r")
```

Now the main code in file `fd_trace.py`, which is tracing all `open` calls and importing `fdmod`, is defined follows:

```
import sys
import inspect
import fdmod

def open_audit_hook(name, *args):
    if name == "open":
        print(name, *args, "was called:")
        caller = inspect.currentframe()
        while caller := caller.f_back:
            print(f"\tFunction {caller.f_code.co_name} "
                  f"in {caller.f_code.co_filename}:"
                  f"{caller.f_lineno}"
            )
sys.addaudithook(open_audit_hook)

# main code
fdmod.foo()
with open("/dev/null", "w") as dev_null:
    dev_null.write("hi")
fdmod.foo()
```

When we run `fd_trace.py`, we will print the call stack whenever some component is calling `open`:

```
% python3 fd_trace.py
open ('/dev/zero', 'r', 524288) was called:
        Function foo in /home/tkrennwa/fdmod.py:2
        Function <module> in fd_trace.py:17
open ('/dev/null', 'w', 524865) was called:
        Function <module> in fd_trace.py:18
open ('/dev/zero', 'r', 524288) was called:
        Function foo in /home/tkrennwa/fdmod.py:2
        Function <module> in fd_trace.py:20
```

See [`sys.audithook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.addaudithook) and [`inspect.currentframe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You might get useful information using `strace`.  This will show all system calls made by a process, including calls to `open()`.  It will not directly show you where in the Python code those calls are occurring, but you may be able to deduce some information from the context.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing open file handles is easy on Linux:

```
open_file_handles = os.listdir('/proc/self/fd')
print('open file handles: ' + ', '.join(map(str, open_file_handles)))
```

You can also use the following on any OS (e.g. Windows, Mac):

```
import errno, os, resource
open_file_handles = []
for fd in range(resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)[0]):
    try: os.fstat(fd)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EBADF: continue
    open_file_handles.append(fd)
print('open file handles: ' + ', '.join(map(str, open_file_handles)))
```

Note: This should always work assuming you're actually (occasionally) running out of file handles. There are usually a max of 256 file handles. But it might take a long time if the max (set by the OS/user policy) is something huge like a billion.

Note also: There will almost always be at least three file handles open for STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR respectively.